# Application Controller method called from ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a method in my application controller.

```
def session_selected(id)
  session[:selected] = [] if session[:selected].blank?
  if session[:selected].include?(id)
    session[:selected].delete(id)
  else
    session[:selected] << id
  end
end
```

I have a call to it from my .js file

```
function check_set(id){
  $.ajax({url: 'session_selected',
  data: {id: id},
  method: 'get'});
  window.location.reload();
}
```

The method never seems to see the id come in from the params...

```
Started GET "/session_selected?id=5" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-27 10:36:45 -0700
Processing by ApplicationController#session_selected as */*
  Parameters: {"id"=>"5"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1ms

ArgumentError - wrong number of arguments (0 for 1):
```

Also, are there any good resources for this?

Comment: first of all `data: id` should be writed as `data: {id: id}`

Comment: Do you have a route to this method. If so, it shouldn't accept any parameters (instead should use `params`). If not, how do you expect to call it via ajax?

Comment: You can't call helper method directly. You will need to make call to an action of controller which can further call helper method

Comment: ok @RAJ... , moved it back to the controller, and it is being called. @LoganSerman, I am trying to set session variables for the selected checkboxes. @ISO4, thanks for clearing that up. However, the controller method doesn't see the `id`.

Comment: @Beengie check `params` in ur `action` you must be getting `id`

Comment: function check_set(id){
      $.ajax({url: 'session_selected',
        method: 'get',
        data: {id: id}});
    }

Comment: `Parameters: {"id"=>"3"}` is coming in, but the method doesn't see it

Comment: better place for `session_selected` is application controller, then just call it from controller action, but if you need helper method you could use `view_context.session_selected(params[:id])`

Comment: `syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')'
  def session_selected(params[:id])`

Comment: `Started GET "/session_selected?id=5" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-27 10:36:45 -0700
Processing by ApplicationController#session_selected as */*
  Parameters: {"id"=>"5"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1ms

ArgumentError - wrong number of arguments (0 for 1):`

Comment: ajax url should be "/session_selected?id="+id

Comment: Just mention the method as `session_selected` and access the `id` in controller method as `params[:id]`.

Comment: it actually was passing that `"/session_selected?id=5"` by the error code above, and hitting the method. However, when I give the method parameter a nil by default `id=nil`, it gives that nil inside the method. So, the method never sees the `id` parameter.

Comment: using `params[:id]` as the parameter for the method returns the following error

    `syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')'
      def session_selected(params[:id])`

Comment: params[:id] is a variable. you cant pass a variable inside a method definition like "def session_selected()"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys for the help

Application Controller

```
def session_selected()
  id = params[:id]
  session[:selected] = [] if session[:selected].blank?
  if session[:selected].include?(id)
    session[:selected].delete(id)
  else
    session[:selected] << id
  end
end
```